# Output specific line number based on pattern

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, grep

I have a file which is 2760 lines with an id on line 2740. In the results I always need it to output line 7 from the top. There are files which contain many more lines and some which contain less but the output is always the value on line 7.

I'm using `grep 'PATTERN' | sed -n '7p' yyyymmdd*.log` this seems to match the pattern but output line 7 from the first file found in the directory.

Would appreciate if someone could give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: did you mean to write `grep 'PATTERN' yyyymmdd*.log | sed -n '7p'` ? also, add sample input(s) and expected output for clarity

Comment: already tried that but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: did you try the answer by @Archemar? and as I asked before, give us sample input files (say 10 lines each) and expected output...

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want the 7th line from each file? The 7th line containing PATTERN from each file? The 7th matching line from the concatenation of the files? Something else? Please edit to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need line 7 of each input file matching a particular filename pattern?

```
awk 'FNR==7' file*
```

The `awk` variable `FNR` will be the line number of the current input file.  If it is 7, the line is printed.

Or, with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -n -s '7p' file*
```

The GNU `sed` option `-s` will make the internal line counter reset between input files (this is a GNU extension to standard `sed`)

If you need to filter the result on some regular expression, either just pipe the output through `grep 'PATTERN'` or, with `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==7 && /PATTERN/' file*
```

or, with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -n -s '7{/PATTERN/p}' file*
```

---

Your command:

```
grep 'PATTERN' | sed -n '7p' yyyymmdd*.log
```

Some issues:

1. The `grep` has no input and will be waiting for input on its standard input stream.
2. The `sed` will only pick up the 7th line from the complete set of input files (i.e. only from the first file).  Its line counter does not reset between files. Using GNU `sed` with `-s`, as above, fixes this.
3. The two parts of the pipeline are not connected. `sed` will not read from `grep`.
4. The `grep` is not needed. You just need line 7.

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
awk '/PATTERN/ { c[FILENAME]++ ; if (c[FILENAME]==7) print ; } ' yyyymmdd*.log
```

where

- the `c[FILENAME]` trick will select 7th line on each file.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `sed`, that should be possible.  For example, in order to only display line number if it includes the `PATTERN` from your file `yyyymmdd*.log`, try:

```
sed -n '2740s/PATTERN/PATTERN/p' yyyymmdd*.log
```

That will preface the `search` command to `sed` with the specified line number (2740), and `-n` and `p` will suppress output unless it's matched.